# Drag and drop with Qt: Knowing target application on hover - is it possible?

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

I'm currently exploring the possibilities of drag-and-drop from a Qt application, into an unknown target application. The question is whether it is possible for the Qt application to receive information about the application that is about to receive the drop (e.g. process name, or title).

A (made up) example could be dragging a plot from a Qt window to either a text editor or a spreadsheet editor. In the former, it would provide the data as an image, in the latter as the data points.

It seems Qt is somewhat aware of what the underlying target of the drop is while hovering, as the actionChanged signal is emitted when changing DropAction state. If I'm not mistaken, it seems that the target application looks at the mime-type contained in the drag object, and signals what the action would be, if dropped there. I'm also not getting anything out of the targetChanged signal (which as far as I can tell is for dropping within the current Qt application).

Any pointers would be helpful, and I'll gladly follow up.

Comment: I know how to do this under Windows, but not portably. Are you interested?

Comment: I'm developing on a cross-platform application, so the Window specific solution wouldn't be very viable. In fact, the drag and drop could be from a Qt program in Linux to, say, Office Word in windows running within a virtual machine. It seems that it could be possible, though I can't figure it out through the Qt documentation. It's still nice to know that Windows supports it, so thanks :) If you have it already written up, or it wouldn't take you long to do so, I wouldn't mind seeing it, but I won't bother you with it if not.

Comment: I always thought the OS/Window manager handled this, and the only consistent (and therefore portable) part of it was the visiblility of the MIME type data.

Comment: As Mike Kwan noted, it is possible in Windows. If it's similarly possible for OS X and X11, which is a reasonable assumption, the intersection of the functionality wold be portable. I don't know the details and issues (or if there is a sensible intersection) regarding portability, and a Qt support. Which is why I'm asking :)

Comment: Did you end up having any success? I'm currently working on something and would like to implement similar functionality. A window that gets dragged on top of my Qt window and I want to get some information such as (PID and maybe X Display number). Currently im running Ubuntu 14.04 and think this should be possible in X

Comment: @mdoran3844, It's been quite a while since I worked on it, and honestly can't remember now. I think I might have had to use `OS` specific calls outside of `Qt`. It should definitely be possible with `X`, as something like `xprop -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) | grep _NET_WM_PID | cut -d' ' -f3` can get the `PID`, and `ps --pid=$pid h -o "%c"` the process name.

Comment: You can add several data types to your drag mime data. So while creating dragable data you can put image and points data (with proper mime-type) and each application will decide what data it wants to take

Comment: I agree with @KamilKlimek, in my opinion it is a very dangerous design to depend on the target application. What if the user has another software to edit documents than the one you expect ? What if the future versions of the software change the name of it ? You should only propose data with standard metadata, not rely on any specific target to adapt (it is the target responsibility to handle what you have to offer).

Comment: @KamilKlimek Your comment should be the accepted answer.

Comment: As the original poster of the question, I too agree with the comment by @KamilKlimek. Providing multiple mime-types and allowing destination application to decide which is appropriate, is the most correct implementation (in general). I think my original question came from curiosity as to what was possible within Qt, and what fell outside and required OS-specific functionality. Feel free to post as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add several data types to your drag mime data. While creating dragable data you can put image and points data (with proper mime-type) and each application will decide what data it accepts and how to interpret it.

For more details check https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html#dragging

Answer (score 0):

You can't really know which application is going to receive your drop. However, that doesn't prevent you from including different format of data in the buffer associated to the drag and drop. Class QMimeData provides the method setData, which takes mimeType as a first argument. You can put some data for a given mimetype, and some other for a different mimeType. It doesn't erase the first one.
Custom mimeData are typically more useful for drops inside your application, but there are some relatively standard ones as : setText, setHtml, setUrls, setImageData, and setColorData.

Typically, you can put both some text and some image in the drag at the same time, and the receiving application should take the one it needs.