# How to detect target when I drag from Qt application and drop to Windows Explorer

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop

I am stucked with one issue while developing application using Qt. My issue is as below:
I have list of files in one list view in my qt application. My requirement is I need to drag one item from list view and drop into Windows Explorer. Now I am not able to find target where user has dropped item. If I do reverse i.e. drop item from Windows Explorer to my qt application then it is possible but I need now reverse way as described above. Let me know whether it is possible or not and if yes then guide me how to achieve it. If any more detail is required then let me know.

Comment: As I know, drag-n-drop mechanics does not support 2 way communication at all. You need to create your own WINAPI code, for example - track mouse event and detect HWND of window, where mouse was released. From this HWND you can get window style (is it support drop) and process ID.

Comment: Seems, that you question is similar with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255582/drag-and-drop-with-qt-knowing-target-application-on-hover-is-it-possible?rq=1